# Change values of numpy array iteratively

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have problems with a numpy array:
a1 is a numpy array ( A 3-dimensional vector) while update is a list of three values. I want that the first dimension of a1 is the first value, the second dimension the second value and the third dimension the third.

```
a1 = [0, 0, 0]
update = [0.6402942957283034, 0.6017736334918196, 0.6096552413265736]
```

So basically, I want:

```
a1 = [0.6402942957283034, 0.6017736334918196, 0.6096552413265736]
```

Now, if I try to iterate:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    a1[i] = update[i]
```

The values in the a1 array have not changed, I still get:

```
a1 = [0, 0, 0]
```

Why does it happen and how do I circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this

```
a1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
update = [0.6402942957283034, 0.6017736334918196, 0.6096552413265736]
for i in range(0,3):
    a1[i] = update[i]
print(a1)
```

which indeed prints `array([0 0 0])`

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because unlike python lists, numpy arrays must contain values of the same type. When you created the array `a1`, you did not specify the type explicitly thus creating an `int64` array. Try doing

```
print(a1.dtype)
```

`update` is a `float64` array where all the numbers are less than 1. When you convert a float < 1 to int, it becomes 0.

The solution to your problem is to explicitly specify the type of array `a1`.

```
a1 = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype='float64')
```

On a different note, why do you copy element by element? You could have done

```
a1 = np.asarray(update)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the reason.

Comment: Strange that for me the `a1` is not `[0,0,0]` but the one which OP wants. The code in the question works for me fine

Comment: @Bazingaa are you using numpy arrays? I am using numpy v1.8.0rc1, Python 2.7.10 on macOS Mojave

Comment: @Lakshay I initializated update as a list because my code wasn't working, i created update to see if it worked with lists, which it did indeed. So my question was more "Why does it work with lists but not with Numpy array". Update was useless in my original code, here I wanted to ask the most general question.

Comment: @Bazingaa I'm in Python 3.6.5 on Anaconda, on Windows 10

Comment: Good catch, I got sidetracked by the assignments in the OP looking like lists.

Comment: @LakshayGarg: I am using python 3.6.5 and numpy '1.14.3'